# apache-spark-Cache table in Memory is spilling over to disk

Tags: apache-spark, caching

How to pin the table in cache so it would not swap out of memory?

**Situation:** We are using **Microstrategy** BI reporting. Semantic layer is built. We wanted to Cache highly used tables into CACHE using Spark SQL CACHE Table ; we did cache for SPARK context( Thrift server). Initially it was all in cache , now some in cache and some in disk. That disk may be local disk relatively more expensive reading than from s3. Queries may take longer and inconsistent times from user experience perspective. If More queries running using Cache tables, copies of the cache table images are copied and copies are not staying in memory causing reports to run longer. so how to pin the table so would not swap to disk. Spark memory management is dynamic allocation, and how to use those few tables to Pin in memory .

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple different ways to tackle this. First keep in mind that in memory storage is shared between storage and execution.  so doing big joins/etc that may require temp storage may be competing for memory space.  You may want to look at "spark.memory.storageFraction"  which currently defaults to 0.5 Consider 0.75 but this will likely slow down your queries.  Also consider applying good data engineering to the problem.  Reduce the amount of data that needs to be stored.  Create a temp view with old records removed and unneeded columns pruned, then cache that.  Consider using smaller datatypes for improved storage.  Ex ints are more space efficient than big strings. Lastly considering switching to an instance type that has more memory available or switching to an instance with fast local disks.  In some situations disk storage isn't that much slower than in memory.  This is particularly true if you're running big complicated analytical queries where the cluster is cpu bound and not io bound.